# limitation of each order in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables `news`, `category`, and `category_request`
I try to fetch all the categories from the news by this query

```
SELECT *
FROM category_request t1 inner join news t2 on t1.news_id  = t2.news_id inner join category t3 on t1.category_id = t3.category_id 
order by t3.title ;
```

and the result is [image: here]

I would love to know if is there any way to get a limit for each order?.

for example just 3 Entertainment news and 3 Feature news
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved it :) Here is the solution if there anyone is interested. select * from (
SELECT *, 
      row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY t3.title
          
          ORDER BY t2.date_updated desc
          
      ) as rn
    FROM category_request t1 inner join news t2 on t1.news_id  = t2.news_id inner join category t3 on t1.category_id = t3.category_id
) as main_categories where rn <= 2;

Answer (score 0):

Windowing functions will do the job :

```
WITH
T AS 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY NULL) AS N
FROM   category_request t1 
       inner join news t2 on t1.news_id  = t2.news_id 
       inner join category t3 on t1.category_id = t3.category_id 
)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  N <= 3
order by title ;
```